# R - Error in using the package ggmosaic

Tags: r, ggplot2, mosaic-plot

I'm using the new package `ggmosaic` to draw mosaic plots with `ggplot2`.

I have an error "Computation failed in `stat_mosaic()`" for just one of the variable from the dataset that I use. The problem seems located around the content of the variable, and more precisely around the treatment of `]` because it works when I replace it by another symbol like `)`.

A simple example :

```
# Parameters
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmosaic)
set.separators(c(":", ";", "|")) # cf. ggmosaic documentation

# Plot OK
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(weight = 1, x = product(TheGroup, TheRange), fill = TheGroup), na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = .1)) +
  labs(x = "TheRange", y = "TheGroup")

# Plot NOK
ggplot(data = df) +
  geom_mosaic(aes(weight = 1, x = product(TheRange, TheGroup), fill = TheRange), na.rm = TRUE) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = .1)) +
  labs(x = "TheGroup", y = "TheRange")
```

And the subset of my data frame with the variable :

```
df <- structure(list(TheRange = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
                                            1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
                                            1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L),
                     .Label = c("(0,30]", "(30,50]", "(50,100]"), class = "factor"),
                     TheGroup = c("Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", 
                                 "Groupe 1", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", 
                                 "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", 
                                 "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", 
                                 "Groupe 1", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 1", 
                                 "Groupe 2", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 1", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", 
                                 "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", 
                                 "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2", "Groupe 2")),
                     .Names = c("TheRange", "TheGroup"),
                row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 
                                               17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 30L, 
                                               31L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 46L, 
                                               47L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L),
                class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bug has been corrected on the last version of ggmosaic (0.1.2).